# segmentation fault for C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My program is a simple "rock paper scissor lizard Spock" program and I wanted to add a 2 player or 1 player vs computer option. This is how I coded the choice part:

```
printf("1.One player OR 2.Two players?\n");
scanf("%d", playerNum);
//input section
printf("1.rock\n2.paper\n3.scissor\n4.spock\n5.lizard\n");
printf("player A enter a choice ");
scanf ("%d", &choiceA);
if (playerNum == 2)
{
    printf("1.rock\n2.paper\n3.scissor\n4.spock\n5.lizard\n");
    printf("player B enter a choice ");
    scanf ("%d", &choiceB);
}
else if (playerNum == 1)
{
    choiceB = 1+rand()%5;
    printf("The computer has picked %d", choiceB);
}
```

When I run the program it gives me a **segmentation fault** right after I enter a value for `playerNum`.
All the variables used in the above are declared as integers.

Comment: it is rock - paper - scissors - lizard - spock

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Your `scanf` expects an argument of `int *` type while you are passing it `int` type argument.
You are missing `&` in `scanf`'s argument.

```
scanf("%d", playerNum);
           ^
           |
        & is missing.
```

Change this to

```
scanf("%d", &playerNum);
```

Comment: this is embarrassing... its such an obvious common mistake i couldnt figure out. thank you so much it works now.